# IIS6 Anonymous Access problem

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I'm having a problem with configuring IIS6 for anonymous access. I've followed most of the suggestions in google search results however, whatever I seem to try results in the site prompting for a username and password.

This is what I've done:

- created a new website in IIS6 using the wizard
- enter the site name "TestSite1"
- leave the IP address unassigned
- set the directory to D:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestSite1
- tick allow anonymous access
- click finish
- changed the permissions for the folder TEstSite1 to allow full access to everyone (temporarily to try and resolve)

WHen I browse to the site from IE or Firefox I'm prompted for a username/password - even though anonymous access is supposedly enabled. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things to try:

- Ensure Integrated Windows Authentication is ticked
- Ensure that the folder has given permissions to *Authenticated Users* and the anonymous IIS user (which I think is IUSR_*machine*)
- If it's an ASP.Net site ensure ASPNET (machine account) user also has access